# Django search on date field with MySQL DB

Tags: django, mariadb

I have a date field in one of my models. I want to develop a search service, which in user sends a query param as search key, for example `'?search=2018'` and the response would be all rows in data base that their date's `year` is `2018`. Or if the user sent `'?search=11'` the response would be all rows that either their date's `month` is `11`, or their date's `day` is `11`.

I am using django 2 and MariaDB version 10.3.18

Here's my model:

```
class MyDate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Please provide some info about the models you're using.

Comment: I edited my question and add my model code. @challet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a controller and http request point of view, you cannot use the same parameter for both condition. It would need, for instance, both a `search_year` and a `search_month`. They also can be combined together.

From a model and SQL query point of view, the Django documentation about [retrieving records with filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) might be of help. There is an exemple there about filtering by years.